# Array of textboxes with same name - javascript validation not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, textbox

This code is not working for me, it's getting submitted without validating.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="skillName[]" id="skillName[]">
<input type="text" name="skillName[]" id="skillName[]">
```

JavaScript:

```
var skillsLength=document.getElementsById("skillName").length;
for(var i=0;i<skillsLength;i++)
{
    if(skillsLength.elements[i].value=="")
    {
        alert("Please Enter a Skill");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the controls are in a form, get a reference to the form and use the repeated *name* attribute: `var inputs = form['skillName[]'];`. You can also use `document.getElementsByName('skillName[]')`.

Comment: You may need to attach your JavaScript code to a submit event. When do you need your code to be called?

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

1. You cannot have two elements with the same id. Use a class (or the name attribute) instead
2. Your ID is `skillName[]` not `skillName`. JavaScript does not give the characters `[]` any special meaning in a name. That is more-or-less unique to PHP.

Such:

```
<input type="text" name="skillName[]" class="skillName">
<input type="text" name="skillName[]" class="skillName">

var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('input.skillName');
```